# find the shortest path between two nodes where the number of edges is minimal

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, hamiltonian-path

Say you are given an undirected unweighted graph, where s and t are nodes from the graph.
d(s,t) means the distance between s and t which outputs the number of edges.

How do I find the the maximum distance between s and t , 
max{d(s,t)}, where the edges between s and t are minimal?
Also, how can this problem can be related/reduced to the hamiltonian problem?

Any advice would be really helpful.

Comment: Where does $s$ come from? Please specify your problem more carefully. What is given and what exactly are you looking for? Also, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Raphael sorry, I will re-define my question as it seems to be confusing.

Comment: Do you only consider *simple* paths? If so, it is certainly related to the hamiltonian path problem: a hamiltonian path exists if for some $s,t$ the maximum distance between $s$ and $t$ is $n-1$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, I am considering simple paths. I am also trying to understand how the shortest-path can be reduced to the hamiltonian-path problem.
hamiltonian-path<=shortest-path.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand your question.  What is given (what are the inputs), and what is the desired output?  max{d(s,t)} doesn't make sense if s,t are two given vertices: d(s,t) is a single integer, so why are you taking a max of a set with one element?  And why do you think this is related to the Hamiltonian path problem?  I think you need to spend more time thinking about this more carefully and figuring out how to explain your problem and articulate it more precisely.

Comment: I also don't understand the question. What do you mean by "where the edges between $s$ and $t$ are minimal"? Is this some kind of weighted graph? If not, I don't see how you can have a path that's simultaneously maximal and minimal (unless it's the only path between the two points).

Comment: @Stella If you can prove that Hamiltonian path reduces to shortest path, you've just proved that **NP=P**.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given a graph $G$, add two new vertices $s,t$, each connected to all vertices in the original graph. When does there exist a path from $s$ to $t$ of length $n+1$?